# Insert data from Aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2NhR.png)I have Cyrillic text for input and Latin for output. in Cyrillic I have a variable and I can insert it in a table
But how can I create a variable for the output as well.
I also need to create a variable for EN (output parameters) so that I can insert it into a table or if there is another option.

```
DECLARE @TEXT NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @TEXT = 'Днес'
DECLARE @EN NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @EN =''


insert into [Anatoli].[dbo].[logg]([date1],lo,[lo1]) values(GETDATE(),@TEXT,ЕN)

SELECT
    @TEXT as BG
   ,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
    (replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
        (replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
            (replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
            (@TEXT,'и','i'),'в','v'),'а','a'),'н','n'),'б','b' )    
                ,'г','g'),'д','d'),'e','е'),'ж','zh'),'з','z'),'й','y'),'к','k')
                    ,'л','l'),'м','m'),'о','o'),'п','p'),'р','r'),'с','s'),'т','t'),'у','u') 
                        ,'ф','f'),'х','h'),'ц','ts'),'ч','ch'),'ш','sh'),'щ','sht'),'ъ','a'),'ь','y')
                        ,'ю','yu'),'я','yа') AS  EN
```

Expected result
on the picture

Comment: Prefix unicode text with N: `SET @TEXT = N'Днес'`, otherwise you'll just get questionmarks. That goes for the values in `replace` as well

Comment: No problem with the input style
rather how to make a variable so I can insert EN result?

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is then, you can just assign the result of the replaces to a variable, much as you do with `@TEXT`

Comment: The output value EN does not allow to stay in a temporary variable and then to set it in the operator for insertion in a table.

Comment: Perhaps `'e','е'` should be `N'е', N'e'`? (The Cyrillic-English parameters are reversed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Cyrillic-Latin translation needs to be reusable it's going to be most versatile in an Inline Table-Valued Function, e.g.:

```sql
create function dbo.app_CyrillicToLatin(
  @Cyrillic nvarchar(1000)
)
returns table as
return (
  select [Latin] =
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@Cyrillic,
      N'и', N'i'), N'в', N'v'), N'а', N'a'), N'н', N'n'), N'б', N'b' ),
      N'г', N'g'), N'д', N'd'), N'е', N'e'), N'ж', N'zh'), N'з', N'z'),
      N'й', N'y'), N'к', N'k'), N'л', N'l'), N'м', N'm'), N'о', N'o'),
      N'п', N'p'), N'р', N'r'), N'с', N's'), N'т', N't'), N'у', N'u'), 
      N'ф', N'f'), N'х', N'h'), N'ц', N'ts'), N'ч', N'ch'), N'ш', N'sh'),
      N'щ', N'sht'), N'ъ', N'a'), N'ь', N'y'), N'ю', N'yu'), N'я', N'yа')
);
go
```

This gives you the flexibility to set variables, as requested, as well as translate in a set-based fashion for INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT operations...

```sql
-- Usage 1, setting a variable
select @EN = Latin
from dbo.app_CyrillicToLatin(@TEXT);

-- Usage 2, translating during insert...
insert into [dbo].[logg] ([date1], [lo], [lo1])
  select getdate(), @TEXT, Latin
  from dbo.app_CyrillicToLatin(@TEXT);

-- Usage 3, translating during update...
update L
set [lo1] = Latin
from [dbo].[logg] L
cross apply dbo.app_CyrillicToLatin([lo]);

-- Usage 4, translating during select...
select [date1], [lo], [Latin] as [lo1]
from [dbo].[logg]
cross apply dbo.app_CyrillicToLatin([lo]);
```